# How can I update ApplicationUser entity and also its custom properties and child objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first

When I tried to update the user table using the following code, it didn't create the new row in the related Filter table which is a custom object I created inside the ApplicationUser class.

```
 using (var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var user = dbContext.Users.Where(u=> u.Id == model.Id)
            if (user.Filter == null)
                 user.Filter = new FilterPal();
            user.Filter.IsFilterOn = model.IsFilterOn;
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the built in functions of UserManager, and not try to update the users table manually.

Example:

```
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    if (user.Filter == null)
        user.Filter = new FilterPal();
    user.Filter.IsFilterOn = model.IsFilterOn;
    UserManager.Update(user);
```

Edit:

It's enough to just use this property:

```
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
    }
    var user = _userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    if (user.Filter == null)
        user.Filter = new FilterPal();
    user.Filter.IsFilterOn = model.IsFilterOn;
    _userManager.Update(user);
```